# Expose functions in a Spreadsheets Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I have an [optimisation addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/opensolver/hfikolkpdcamjmmpoamebnahmiinpbfm) for Google Spreadsheets that allows users to form and solve mathematical programs. This is currently done through the addon sidebar, but users have requested the ability to also be able to do this programmatically.

My first thought was to separate out some of the functionality into a library so that both the addon and users can reference this library. The problem is that some of the main functionality they would want (the `solve` function) depends on interacting with the sheet to which the addon is bound, and for this reason I believe it cannot exist as a library function. It needs to get and set values on the sheet.

Is there any way I can offer users a programmatic way to access my addon's solve function from within their own apps-script project?

Comment: Surely your solve function receives the calculable values as passed parameters? Or could be rewritten to do so? If so then describe what each if the passed variables needs to be in your library documentation.

Comment: As part of the solve function, we use numerical differentiation to determine the coefficients in the model. This requires setting cell values on the sheet, recalculating the sheet, and then reading off the results. The model we construct then gets passed to the LinearOptimizationService for solving.

If the user already knows the values this differentiation will produce then they should skip our addon entirely and pass the values into the LinearOptimizationService themselves.

Comment: Sounds like you need to drill down into your users' request to access programmatically. Are they in fact asking if the calculation in the sheet can be happening in code directly?

Comment: What they want to do is to be able to is to make whatever changes to the sheet they need in their own scripts, and then fire our solve function from their code rather than needing to click the button in the addon. Sounds like its not possible in the current state until we do the calculation ourselves in the code rather than offloading to the sheet as you suggest. That's on the roadmap but a while off yet. Thanks!